# AngularJS Rails X-CSRF-TOKEN Disable For One Page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I'm working on an example from the book "AngularJS + Rails".  One example was accessing the Git Repository Api to pull repositories from Github based off a username.  This functionality worked fine until the next chapter extended the angular $http module to play nice with Rails Cross-Site Request Forgery protection.  When I go back and use the Github page, Github rejects the connection with the following error.

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.github.com/users/dhh/repos.
Request header field X-CSRF-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

The code that breaks the functionality in angular:

```
AngulaRails.config ["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Accept = "application/json"
]
```

So I know I have to disable CSRF for the one page that is throwing the error.  What code will accomplish this?  Can you give a quick explanation of what is actually happening when I change the $httpProvider defaults?  Why does it break the page?